# Cannot locate new sub classed property in winforms control

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Thanks to help in here I've managed to recursively loop through all the controls on my winform and locate my sub classed control but when I try to update my user defined properties _key and _value the object ctrl does not expose them :(
I'm using 
ctrlContainer below is the calling form passed as this

```
foreach (Control ctrl in ctrlContainer.Controls)
{
    // code to find my specific sub classed textBox
    // found my control
    // now update my new property _key
    ctrl._key does not exist :(

    I know the ctrl exists and is valid because ctrl.Text = "I've just added this text" works.
    _key is visible when looking at the control in the form designer.
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your reference is of type `Control` (`foreach (Control ctrl`), which I'm assuming is not your sub-classed control. That reference will only understand members that belong to it, `_key` presumably belongs to a derived class. Try this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in ctrlContainer.Controls)
{
    // code to find my specific sub classed textBox
    // found my control
    // now update my new property _key
    if (ctrl is MyControl)
    {
        MyControl myControl = (MyControl)ctrl;
        myControl._key = "";
    }
}
```

Or your can change your iterator to find only instances of your control, as suggested by Sebastian. This would be cleaner code.

Comment: This one worked for me because foreach (var ctrl in ctrlContainer.Controls.OfType<ucSelfLoadingTextBoxA>()) messed up the code that looked for any textboxes inside a control eg Group box.

Answer (score 4):

`_key` does not exist because you are looking at a `Control`.

try doing :

```
foreach (var ctrl in ctrlContainer.Controls.OfType<MyControl>())
{
     ctrl._key = "somthing";
}
```

Comment: That way you are only iterationg the container for controls of your current control type, which are guaranteed to have the `_key` property; by doing it the way you posted in the question, you can't guarantee all controls are of that type (in fact they wont).

Comment: Well the resulting iteration would be the same, all types checked. However the linq variety embeds the check into the iterator itself, whereas otherwise you'd have to check manually as per my answer. That said, I do prefer the Linq approach, +1.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth just in case, my answer was for the now deleted comment not to yours (which I think you are referring to!).

Comment: Yeah I guessed as much, but I thought I'd still explain how the OfType iteration still touches all entities and that both pieces of code would essentially be equivalent :-)